# Why does Mule restart every 10 minutes when I use the AMQP transport

Tags: mule, amqp, restart

This is my old xml file:

```
<amqp:connector name="amqp_config" validateConnections="true" host="${amqp.host}" virtualHost="${amqp.virtualHost}" username="${amqp.username}" password="${amqp.password}" doc:name="AMQP Connector"/>
```

If I use this configuration, when RabbitMQ restarts, Mule doesn't reconnect to RabbitMQ ,so I changed the configuration like this :

```
<amqp:connector name="amqp_config" validateConnections="true" host="${amqp.host}" virtualHost="${amqp.virtualHost}" username="${amqp.username}" password="${amqp.password}" doc:name="AMQP Connector">
    <reconnect-forever frequency="${amqp.reconnect.time}" blocking="false" />
</amqp:connector>
```

but this configuration will let the mule restart every 10 minutes, so I changed the configuration file back, but Mule still restart every 10 minutes.

Comment: What's the value of `amqp.reconnect.time`? When Mule restarts, what do you see in the logs? It's impossible to help you without more context.

Comment: the amqp.reconnect.time=10000 and when the mule restart the log is the  same with the log when I start the mule.

Comment: and when I change back the xml file, mule still restart.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the configuration you think you are running? What does the log say when Mule restart?

Comment: Also please specify the versions of: RabbitMQ, Mule and the AMQP transport you are using.

Comment: The log is too long, could I mail to you?

Comment: RabbitMQ3.1.1    Mule 3.4   AMQP transport 3.3.0.1

Comment: Is it Mule 3.4.0 CE? or EE? or 3.4.1 EE? Just put in your question the few lines of the log when Mule restarts so we can see what triggers the restart.